# why cant't direct visit hashmap static variable

Tags: java

When I study HashMap source code, I found the HashMap class have many static variable, sush as:

```
public class HashMap<K,V>
extends AbstractMap<K,V>
implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable
{
    /**
     * The default initial capacity - MUST be a power of two.
     */
    static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

    /**
     * The maximum capacity, used if a higher value is implicitly specified
     * by either of the constructors with arguments.
     * MUST be a power of two <= 1<<30.
     */
    static final int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;

    /**
     * The load factor used when none specified in constructor.
     **/
    static final float DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f;
```

Why can't I use these static variable?

Comment: Because they're not public?

Comment: Those aren't variables, they're constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are package private, meaning that you can directly access them if and only if your class is located in a package with the same name.

Declaring a field without an access modifier (such as `public`, `private` or `protected`) makes it package private.

However, as some people have pointed out, in this particular case you shouldn't need to care about the fields (perhaps unless you are extending `HashMap` for an own implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Because their access level is package, meaning that only classes from the same package can access them. They are not meant for public use. You can read details on member access rules [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).